# Create Event Listener For Dynamically Created HTML element

Tags: angular, typescript, mouseevent, addeventlistener

Inside the "downMouseBtn(event)" Event Handler, 
i created element  `<div id ="rectangle"></ div>`

I need to create an eventListener for the created item.

How can I create this?
What part of the code to add it?

I need to handle the mouseClick event for a dynamically generated item.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({ selector: 'app-editor', templateUrl:'./editor.component.html', styleUrls: ['./editor.component.css']})

export class EditorComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private elRef: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  downMouseBtn(event) {
    this.rectangle = document.createElement('div'); /*dynamically create element*/
    this.rectangle.setAttribute("id", "rectangle"); /*set id for element*/

    this.renderer.appendChild(this.editorPhotoWrapper.nativeElement, this.rectangle); /*add element via renderer*/

    /* problemAreaStart */
    this.renderer.listen(this.rectangle.nativeElement, 'click', (event) => {
      console.log("test");
    });    
    /* problemAreaStop */
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you need to create the component this way? Is the component details comming from your api?

Comment: Component details are not comming from API, but when "downMouseBtn (event)" is triggered, new component should be created in the html page. I chose this path of implementation, since I thought that the ".addEventListener ()" function works in Angular, but when I use, I get the error "element is undefined". What other ways are there to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm researching to understand why that is not working. In the mean time, a workaround may be possible if you create an angular component (rectangleComponent) and show/hide it with *ngIf structural directive

Comment: I can not apply directives, because It is not known how many times "downMouseBtn (event)" triggered (and how many new `<div id = "rectangle"> </ div>` will be added to the html page).

Comment: on every downMouseBtn(event) you can push an element to a dummy array and use *ngFor to create a rectangule component for every dummy element <div *ngFor="dummyElement in dummyArray"><rectangle (click)="doSomething()"></rectangle></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({ selector: 'app-editor', templateUrl:'./editor.component.html', styleUrls: ['./editor.component.css']})

export class EditorComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private elRef: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  downMouseBtn(event) {
    this.rectangle = this.renderer.createElement('div'); /*dynamically create element*/
    // this.rectangle.setAttribute("id", "rectangle"); /*forget this by now*/

    this.renderer.appendChild(this.editorPhotoWrapper.nativeElement, this.rectangle); /*add element via renderer*/

    /* problemAreaStart */
    this.renderer.listen(this.rectangle, 'click', (event) => {
      console.log("test");
    });    
    /* problemAreaStop */
  }
}
```

let's try to not touch DOM directly, use render2 instead, when possible.

here is a link to an article from alligator.io wich was the base of my answer:
https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/

Comment: What if there is a separate templateUrl: './editor.component.html'?

Comment: there is no problem. i just made it that way to make the answer simpler to read and understand :)

Comment: I corrected the condition, can you please re-consider it ?

Comment: I now understand better your question. I'll try to find a more adequate answer and replace this answer by it

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!

Comment: you're welcome. don't forget to aprove the answer if it was usefull and rate it up :)