# How to add an event listener to dynamically generated content using Renderer2?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-renderer2

I am trying to add a `click` event listener to a `div` that is dynamically generated after page load but I can't seem to get the event to register. I am following the instructions found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56996242/6480913) however, it is not working for me.

In my `ngOnInit()` I have a `combineLatest()`:

```
combineLatest([this.params$, this.user$]).subscribe(([params, user]: [Params, User]) => {   
    this.artistId = parseInt(params['artist']);   
    this.user = user;

  if (this.artistId) {
    this.artistProfileGQL.watch({
      id: this.artistId
    }).valueChanges.subscribe((response: ApolloQueryResult<ArtistProfileQuery>) => {
      this.artist = response.data.artist;
      this.initElements(); // WHERE I CALL TO INITIALIZE DYNAMIC DOM ELEMENTS
    }); 
})
```

In this block, I call `initElements()` which is where I create certain `DOM` elements. I've included most of them below. Essentially, I have a header element, and inside this header element, I create a `followBtn`, that looks like this (i removed the title, followers, elements etc from the code for brevity). I added comments in caps for the most relevant lines:

[image]

```
initElements() {
  const parentElement = this.el.nativeElement;
  this.header = parentElement.querySelector('ion-header');

  // Create image overlay
  this.imageOverlay = this.renderer.createElement('div');
  this.renderer.addClass(this.imageOverlay, 'image-overlay');

  this.colorOverlay = this.renderer.createElement('div');
  this.renderer.addClass(this.colorOverlay, 'color-overlay');

  this.colorOverlay.appendChild(this.imageOverlay);
  this.header.appendChild(this.colorOverlay);

  var artistHeader = this.renderer.createElement('div');
  this.renderer.addClass(artistHeader, 'artist-header');

  // HERES WHERE I CREATE MY BUTTON ELEMENT
  this.followBtn = this.renderer.createElement('div');
  this.renderer.addClass(this.followBtn, "follow-btn");
  var followText = this.renderer.createText('FOLLOW');
  this.renderer.appendChild(this.followBtn, followText);

  this.renderer.appendChild(artistHeader, this.followBtn);

  this.renderer.appendChild(this.imageOverlay, artistHeader);

  // HERES WHERE I CREATE MY LISTENER
  this.followButtonListener = this.renderer.listen(this.followBtn, 'click', (event) => {
    console.log(event);
  });

}
```

However, when I click on the element, I don't get anything printed to my console. If I change the `target` of the `listener` to a `DOM` element, the click listener works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It can be a css issue because it works for me

Comment: @yurzui interesting, css can prevent an event listener from attaching?

Comment: Some block can overlap other

Comment: ugh yep, the `image-overlay` had a css property called `pointer-events` set to `none` which was preventing child elements from binding to click elements. Thank you!